# Search with SOUNDEX MYSQL laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, elasticsearch, search

Hi guys I have a problem with soundex in laravel 
here is my query

```
 $data = Post::whereRaw("SOUNDEX('title_am') = SOUNDEX('corona')")
        ->orWhereRaw("SOUNDEX('title_en') = SOUNDEX('corona')")
        ->orWhereRaw("SOUNDEX('title_ru') = SOUNDEX('corona')")
        ->get(); //return []
```

please help me!!